# What python 3 library should I use for MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

As far as I know MySQLdb still isn't ported to Python 3.

There seems to be another library called PyMySQL on pypy but the installation for python 3 looks strange (run a .sh script?). Also there is a library called PyMySQL3 but I can't find info about what it's about.

What's the preferred way to use MySQL with Python 3 these days?

Is there an elegant solution that could be installed with pip or with a `python setup.py install` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the basic [mysql-connector](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/1.0.10) from MySQL for a few Python 3 projects, along with SQLAlchemy.

I also tried [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/), but if I remember correctly I had a more difficult time configuring it.

Comment: Awesome, mysql-connector seems to be working. Supported by the mysql team and I could install it very easily with pip (`pip-python3 install mysql-connector-python`). I just created a table. I hope everything else works too but I see no reason why it wouldn't. Thank you very much!

Comment: mysql-connector is externally hosted, so, now, in March 2015, it's necessary to do  `pip3 install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python` to install it

Comment: Update: now in October 2016 the '--allow-external' option is deprecated. To install mysql-connector now, you have to specify directly the url of the setup archive (hosted on the mysql servers): `pip3 install http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.zip#md5=3df394d89300db95163f17c843ef49df` It is possible to obtain the latest url for the file on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/

Answer (score 1):

For people porting code that previously used [`MySQL-python` on Python 2](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) (imported with `import MySQLdb`), the drop-in replacement is [`mysqlclient`](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/), a fork of `MySQL-python` that:

1. Is imported under the same name (`MySQLdb`)
2. Remains C-accelerated for speed
3. Is compatible with Python 2 and 3 and fixes several bugs from the original `MySQL-python`

`mysql-connector` is perfectly fine (it's the Oracle developed solution), though the interface differs a bit, and being implemented in Python makes it slower. Same general comments apply to `PyMySQL`. If performance/compatibility doesn't matter, all of them are good, but for maximum performance and full compatibility with `MySQL-python`/`MySQLdb`, you want `mysqlclient` (for a code-base that's otherwise fully Py2/Py3 compatible, it will work on either version, and require no changes to the source code, just the dependencies declared in `setup.py`).