# What STANDARD module should I use with Python 3 to talk to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

This [earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966468/what-python-3-library-should-i-use-for-mysql) suggests [mysql.connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/), which is what I am actually using.  However, as noted in a comment to the accepted answer in the aforementioned question, this is *not a standard python module*.

My problem:  whenever my ISP upgrades to a newer Python version, I have to notice the crashes and bug them to install mysql.connector for me.

I *could* explicitly call for an older version of Python 3.x.  However, all other things being equal, I'd like to use the latest Python, and it seems like MySQL is just such a standard of standards that there really should be a *standard* Python 3 library for it.  Is there?  I'm not doing anything fancy with the database (or with python), so basic functionality is o.k.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and isolate yourself from ISP python upgrades:

```
pyvenv ./mysqlvenv
./mysqlvenv/bin/pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

install your other dependencies using ./mysqlvenv/bin/pip install foo and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Never heard of venv, thanks for the idea.  It is similar to a Docker?   (something I've heard about but never used)   I'll have to investigate if my ISP supports/allows this.

Comment: venv is part of python 3.x now, so your ISP has it, unless they customised their setup. Docker is container virtualization, so it encompasses venv.